# Trying to execute the php script on sendmail.php page on a html button click using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

When the user submits the form i want the sendmail.php to be executed and the data should be inserted in the local db. But that doesn't seem to happen. But if i place the sendmail.php code in the same file i.e index.php it works, but i don't want that as it poses a security threat.

The ajax is after the form and both the files i.e index.php and sendmail.php are in the same folder.

this is my ajax script on same page i.e index.php

```
<script>
        jQuery('#get-quote').on('submit',function(e)
        
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            //jQuery('#msg').html('');
            jQuery('#Submit').html('Please Wait');
            jQuery('#Submit').attr('disabled',true);
            $.ajax({
                url:'send-mail.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:jQuery('#get-quote').serialize(),
                success:function(result){
                    jQuery('#msg').html(result);
                    jQuery('#Submit').html('Submit');
                    jQuery('#Submit').attr('disabled',false);
                    jQuery('#get-quote')[0].reset();
                }
            });
            
        });
    </script>
```

this is the form in index.php

```
 <div class="pinside10">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-scroll" id="section-apply">
                <div class="bg-light pinside30">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                            <div class="section-title mb60 text-center">
                                <h1>Get a Quote</h1>
                                <p>Now apply for a any Loan online, All you need to do is provide your details below application form.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                            <form class="" id="get-quote" name="get-quote" method="post">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <!-- Text input-->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class=" form-group ">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                                                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required>
                                                <span class="help-block"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group ">
                                                <label class=" control-label" for="email">E-Mail</label>
                                                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control input-md">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Text input-->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group ">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
                                                <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group ">

                                                <label for="amount" class="control-label">Loan Amount</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Enter your amount" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <label for="years" class="control-label">Year</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="years" name="years" placeholder="Enter number of years(eg:1,2,3)" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Button -->
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <button id="Submit"  name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit New Quote</button>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <span id="msg"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the sendmail.php file i'm trying to execute when the user clicks submit button

```
<?php


$msg="";

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loans4you');
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    
        $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
        $amount=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['amount']);
        $years=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['years']);

        mysqli_query($con,"insert into getquote(name,email,phone,amount,years) values('$name','$email','$phone','$amount','$years')");
        $msg="Thank you!";

       

        echo $msg;
    
}




?>
```

Comment: `on('Submit'` <= lowercase that `S`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: it still wont work i tried both 'S' and 's' @Taplar

Comment: I didnt make that comment, @Taplar did

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: I assume `send-mail.php` is in the same folder as `index.php`?

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Do you see the request attempting to be made in the network console?

Comment: Also does your script appear before or after your form in your html document?

Comment: _"if i place the sendmail.php code in the same file i.e index.php it works, but i don't want that as it poses a security threat"_ ...how exactly? You mean because anyone could send a request to it? yes that's true. But if you put it somewhere outside the website's folder, then _no-one_ can send a request to it, including your own code. Instead, if you want to make it hard for people to send spam email through your script, use something like a Captcha to make it difficult for non-humans to use the endpoint, or for anyone to send a request without going through your form.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes they are in the same folder.

Comment: @Taplar no i dont see any console requests and the script appears after the  form.

Comment: Then yeah, take a look at the answer below as `e` is undefined in your event handler.

Comment: @Taplar yes tried that but doesn' t work. i think the script has some problem or is there any other way to access the sendmail.php rather than using ajax?

Comment: If you fixed the `Submit` issue, and the `e` not existing issue, please update your question to show the current version of the code that is not working.

Comment: @Taplar I have updated the code. You can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault(); does nothing since "e" is not passed as event in function call. That's why it seems to work when renamed to index. basically your script does not exec the ajax ,just submits form data instead.
place e.preventDefault() as first line in function call, ad "e", and many other small changes. php code is insecure.

Comment: Okay i did the 'e' in argument. still doesnt seem to work. And what are the other changes? @Paun Narcis Iulian

Comment: @Sarcasm Please be specific. What's not working? check out your code here, https://jsfiddle.net/alpenzoo/th7L4edg/ html and js seems to be fine, check network, data is getting sent. Post errors, network requests, something.